# Java String conversion describe hierarchy of elements based on parentheses similar to JSON hierarchy

Tags: java, string, converters

Convert the string: 
        "(id,created,employee(id,firstname,employeeType(id), lastname),location)" 
        to the following output

```
    id 
    created 
    employee 
    - id 
    - firstname 
    - employeeType 
    — id 
    - lastname 
    location 

    Bonus (output in alphabetical order): 
    created 
    employee 
    - employeeType 
    — id 
    - firstname 
    - id 
    - lastname 
    id
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: You may want to publish this challenge in HackerRank

Comment: Well I tried few approaches but they are quite static I need a more dynamic way of handling different parameter.

Comment: public static void splitStringByParentheses(String stringToManipulate){
  
  StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder(stringToManipulate);
  strBuilder.deleteCharAt(0);
  strBuilder.replace(2, 3, "\n");
  strBuilder.replace(10, 11, "\n");
  strBuilder.replace(19, 20, "\n -");
  strBuilder.replace(24, 25, "\n -");
  //razbra ideqta
  System.out.println(strBuilder);      
  
 }

Comment: public static void splitString(String stringToSplit){
  
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  
  char[] charArray = stringToSplit.toCharArray();  
  
  for(int i = 1; i < charArray.length - 1; i++){   
   char character = charArray[i];
   // "String" 'char' sintaxis
   if(character == ')'){
    sb.insert(0, '-');
    continue;
   }
   if(character == ','){
    System.out.println(sb);
    //sb empty
    sb.append("- ");
   }
   //sb.append(arg0)
   /*finally{
     
   }*/
   
  }